# Do I need @capacitor/angular and @capacitor/assets and what do they do?

Tags: angular, capacitor

I'm building an application with Capacitor but have noticed that `@capacitor/angular` and `@capacitor/assets` have not been updated in over a year.

When looking for answers I cannot seem to find reference to them or what they do.
Are they required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@capacitor/assets` was updated 3 months ago.
It's a tool for generating images for splash screen plugin and app icons. So you don't need it if you generate those manually or with other tooling/software.

`@capacitor/angular` are schematics for angular that allow to add Capacitor to an angular app in an easier way than manually. So if you run `ng add @capacitor/angular` it would install the required dependencies and init your project, instead of you installing the dependencies manually and running `npx cap init` command to init the project.